# Get 2 contents per line

Tags: php

I was wondering I can get these to the ID and the Name from this code:

```
    stuffyd[1] = {name: "Item 1"};
stuffyd[2] = {name: "Item 2"};
stuffyd[3] = {name: "Item 3"};
stuffyd[4] = {name: "Item 4"};
stuffyd[5] = {name: "Item 5"};
stuffyd[6] = {name: "Item 6"};
```

The ID is in the [IDHERE] and the name, obviously is after name:
I tried using explode and loops but that didn't work out well. Here was my code:

```
    <?php
function getItemName($i) {
    $itemNameFile = file_get_contents('test.txt');
    $itemName = explode('"', $itemNameFile);
    return $itemName[$i];
}
function getItemID($i) {
    $itemIDFile = file_get_contents('test.txt');
    $itemID1 = explode('stuffyd[', $itemIDFile);
    $itemID = explode(']', $itemID1[$i]);
    return $itemID[0];
}
function getNamesID() {
    for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
        //if ($i & 1) {
            $itemName1 = getItemName($i);
        //}
        //if($i < 6) {
            $itemID1 = getItemID($i);
        //}
    }
    echo $itemName1 . ":" . $itemID1 . chr(10);
}
getNamesID();
?>
```

This is the output: 
Item 3:5

What can I do?

Comment: Use `preg_match_all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// read the file once only
$data = file_get_contents('test.txt');

// use preg_match_all to parse the data
preg_match_all("/stuffyd\[([0-9]+)\].*\"(.*?)\"/im", $data, $matches);

// you could echo here but let's convert the matches into a usable array
$count=count($matches);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
    $items[$matches[1][$i]]=$matches[2][$i];
}

// and then echo out the key and value of each pair
foreach ($items as $id => $name){
    echo $name . ':' . $id . chr(10);
}
```

https://www.php.net/preg_match_all

Comment: it looks like the OP wants `echo $value . ':' . $key . chr(10);` instead of `echo $key . ':' . $value . chr(10);`

Comment: This is what I wanted but it only show up to 9 lines/items, is it possible to make it up to 25?                                                           EDIT: NVM, Thanks! I just added {0,25} after 0-9

Comment: I had a minor typo in this line. `preg_match_all("/stuffyd\[([0-9]+)\].*\"(.*?)\"/im", $data, $matches);` Update the code and it will handle as many as you give it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$contents = file_get_contents("test.txt");
preg_match_all('/stuffyd\[(\d+)\].*=name:\s*"(.*)"/', $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo $match[2] . ':' . $match[1] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers really take away from the answer. Add some explanation on what's happening.

Comment: It's so simple it should be self-evident. Anything not immediately obvious can be found in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The answers by @Popnoodles and @Barmar are best using `preg_match_all`.

But to understand why your code didn't work, there are 3 issues.

(1) in `function getItemName($i)` when you explode `$itemNameFile` the array in `$itemName` look like -

```
Array
(
    [0] => stuffyd[1] = {name: 
    [1] => Item 1
    [2] => };
stuffyd[2] = {name: 
    [3] => Item 2
    [4] => };
stuffyd[3] = {name: 
    [5] => Item 3
    [6] => };
stuffyd[4] = {name: 
    [7] => Item 4
    [8] => };
stuffyd[5] = {name: 
    [9] => Item 5
    [10] => };
stuffyd[6] = {name: 
    [11] => Item 6
    [12] => };
)
```

So you need to do

```
return $itemName[$i+($i-1)];
```

(2) in `function getNamesID()` you are only looping through 5 time

```
for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++)
```

to get all 6 you need to use `<=6`

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++)
```

(3) in `function getNamesID()` your `echo ...` is outside of your `for()` loop, so you will only get the last instance. Move the `for()` loop closing bracket to after your echo -

```
echo $itemName1 . ":" . $itemID1 . chr(10);
} // end for()
} // end function
```

So now your code would look like -

```
<?php
function getItemName($i) {
    $itemNameFile = file_get_contents('test.txt');
    $itemName = explode('"', $itemNameFile);
    return $itemName[$i+($i-1)];
}
function getItemID($i) {
    $itemIDFile = file_get_contents('test.txt');
    $itemID1 = explode('stuffyd[', $itemIDFile);
    $itemID = explode(']', $itemID1[$i]);
    return $itemID[0];
}
function getNamesID() {
    for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
        $itemName1 = getItemName($i);
        $itemID1 = getItemID($i);
        echo $itemName1 . ":" . $itemID1 . chr(10);
    }
}
getNamesID();
?>
```